# Insert using Linq-to-SQL where IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to insert a new row into a table **without inserting an identity. I'm just inserting to the other columns.** I want the identity to be created automatically.

Simplified code:

```
Table<Class1> customers = db.GetTable<Class1>();
customers.InsertOnSubmit(new Class1 { Prop1 = "test });
try { db.SubmitChanges(); }
catch (ChangeConflictException ex) { }
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Log' when
>   IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

I assume Linq2SQL updates all columns automatically. But how do I get around it? I've even tried to just leave out that column from the class, but then Linq2SQL tells me that:

> Can't perform Create, Update, or Delete operations on 'Table(Class1)'
>   because it has no primary key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your property should have the following properties:

```
[Column(Storage="ColumnID", AutoSync=AutoSync.Always, DbType="Int NOT NULL 
     IDENTITY", IsDbGenerated=true)]
public int ColumnID
```

**If your column table has the auto-identity in database, then try recreate or update your `LINQ TO SQL` DB Context.**

Comment: Thanks. But I don't want to insert an identity. I want it to be created automatically.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that. I assume that's _instead_ of the first code. Correct?

Comment: `IsDbGenerated=true` did it. Thanks!

Comment: @ispiro I am glad to help you!:)